# How to add column filter for status column in ascending/descending order in magento grid for custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, filter

I want to sort this order in status column =>  1.active  2. On hold 3. out of stock.

But my status column is sort in this order=>  1.active  2. out of stock 3. On hold.

here is my code:
**grid.php**

```
<?php
class Assel_Allstock_Block_Adminhtml_Allstock_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('allstockGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('stock_status');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
     if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('website')) {
        $storeIds = Mage::app()->getWebsite($this->getRequest()->getParam('website'))->getStoreIds();
        $storeId = array_pop($storeIds);
    } else if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('group')) {
        $storeIds = Mage::app()->getGroup($this->getRequest()->getParam('group'))->getStoreIds();
        $storeId = array_pop($storeIds);
    } else if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('store')) {
        $storeId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
    } else {
        $storeId = '';
    }


    $product_id=$this->getRequest()->getParam('product_id');
    //$product_id=1829;
    $collection = Mage::getModel('po/poproduct')->getCollection()
                              ->addFieldToSelect('*')
                              ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.stock_status',array('neq'=>'deleted'))
                              ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.product_id',$product_id);
    $collection->getSelect()->join( 
                                   array('po'=> purchase_order_cr), 
                                   'po.po_id = main_table.po_id', 
                                   array('po.supplier_id','po.supplier_company','po.invoice_number','po.received_date','po.po_net_amount','po.po_net_due_amount') // field to be taken in grid
                             );

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}


/* overwrite to sort stock_status column in grid*/
protected function _setCollectionOrder($column)
{
    $collection = $this->getCollection();
    if ($collection) {
         switch ($column->getId()) { 
              case 'stock_status':
                $arr = array();
                $i=0;
                foreach($collection as $item)  
                { 
                    if($item->getStockStatus()=="stock on hold")  // check value of column
                    {
                        $item->setStockStatus("on hold");        // replace value of column
                    }   

                    $arr[$i] = $item;   
                    $i++    ;        
                }

                $collectionItems = $collection->getItems();
                usort($collectionItems, array($this, '_sortItems'));  // re-sort collection
                $newCollection = new Varien_Data_Collection();        // create new collection

                foreach ($collectionItems as $item) {
                    $newCollection->addItem($item);                // assign each item to new collection
                }
                $this->setCollection($newCollection);

                break;
            default:
                parent::_setCollectionOrder($column);
                break;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

/* custom function to sort stock_status column in grid*/
public function _sortItems($a, $b)
{
    $columnId = "stock_status";
    $dir      = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameDir(), $this->_defaultDir);

    $al = strtolower($a->getData($columnId));
    $bl = strtolower($b->getData($columnId));

    if ($al == $bl) {
        return 0;
    }

    if ($dir == 'asc') {
        return ($al < $bl) ? -1 : 1;
    } else {
        return ($al > $bl) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{

    // hidden column
    $this->addColumn('po_id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('allstock')->__('PO Id'),
        'align' => 'center',
        'width' => '100px',
        'index' => 'po_id',
        'column_css_class'=>'no-display',
        'header_css_class'=>'no-display'
    ));

    // hidden column
    $this->addColumn('po_product_id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('allstock')->__('Po product Id'),
        'align' => 'center',
        'width' => '100px',
        'index' => 'po_product_id',
        'column_css_class'=>'no-display',
        'header_css_class'=>'no-display'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('image', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('allstock')->__('Image'),
        'align' => 'center',
        'width' => '10px',
        'index' => 'product_id',
        'renderer' => 'allstock/adminhtml_allstock_renderer_image'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('supplier_id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('allstock')->__('Supplier'),
        'align' => 'left',
        'width' => '500px',
        'index' => 'supplier_id',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'filter_index'=>'po.supplier_id',
        'options' => Mage::helper('allstock')->getSupplierOption()
    ));

    $this->addColumn('invoice_number', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('allstock')->__('Invoice'),
        'align' => 'center',
        'width' => '100px',
        'index' => 'invoice_number',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('received_date', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('allstock')->__('Invoice Date'),
        'align' => 'center',
        'width' => '250px',
        'index' => 'received_date',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billed_qty', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('allstock')->__('Billed Qty'),
        'align' => 'center',
        'width' => '200px',
        'index' => 'billed_qty',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('free_qty', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('allstock')->__('Free Qty'),
        'align' => 'center',
        'width' => '200px',
        'index' => 'free_qty',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('current_stock_qty', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('allstock')->__('Current Qty'),
        'align' => 'center',
        'width' => '200px',
        'index' => 'current_stock_qty',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('dead_qty', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('allstock')->__('Dead Qty'),
        'align' => 'center',
        'width' => '200px',
        'index' => 'dead_qty',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('expiry_date', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('allstock')->__('Exp. Date'),
        'align' => 'center',
        'width' => '200px',
        'index' => 'expiry_date',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('special_offer', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('allstock')->__('Sp. Offer'),
        'align' => 'left',
        'width' => '200px',
        'index' => 'special_offer',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('mrp', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('allstock')->__('MRP'),
        'width' => '50px',
        'align' => 'center',
        'index' => 'mrp',
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'renderer' => 'allstock/adminhtml_allstock_renderer_priceformat'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('cost', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('allstock')->__('Cost'),
        'width' => '10px',
        'align' => 'center',
        'index' => 'cost',
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'renderer' => 'allstock/adminhtml_allstock_renderer_priceformat'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('special_price', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('allstock')->__('Sp. Price'),
        'width' => '10px',
        'align' => 'center',
        'index' => 'special_price',
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'renderer' => 'allstock/adminhtml_allstock_renderer_priceformat'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('stock_status', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('allstock')->__('Status'),
        'width' => '200px',
        'align' => 'center',
        'index' => 'stock_status',
        'renderer' => 'allstock/adminhtml_allstock_renderer_stockstatus'
    ));


    $this->addColumn('po_net_amount', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('allstock')->__('Net Amt'),
        'width' => '200px',
        'align' => 'center',
        'index' => 'po_net_amount',
    //  'renderer' => 'allstock/adminhtml_allstock_renderer_stockstatus'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('po_net_due_amount', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('allstock')->__('Net Due Amt'),
        'width' => '200px',
        'align' => 'center',
        'index' => 'po_net_due_amount',
    //  'renderer' => 'allstock/adminhtml_allstock_renderer_stockstatus'
    ));


    $this->addColumn('view', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('allstock')->__('View'),
        'width' => '200px',
        'align' => 'center',
        'renderer' => 'allstock/adminhtml_allstock_renderer_viewurl'
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

// Used for AJAX loading
public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true,"gridType"=>"allstock"));
}
```

Comment: What happens when you click on your status header on top?

Comment: so it gets sorted? then what is your qst? Sorry I don't follow.